# JPA Single Table Inheritance: Not a managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application (embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template...) using

```
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
```

I use Inheritance strategies with JPA and Hibernate

I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_alarm_notification")
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name= "ALARM_TYPE")
public abstract class AlarmNotification  implements Serializable {
..
}
```

and this other one:

```
   @MappedSuperclass
    public class BookAlarmNotification extends AlarmNotification {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Book book;

..
}
```

and this other one

```
public interface BookAlarmNotificationRepository extends CrudRepository<BookAlarmNotification, Long> {

}
```

but running an integration test or just starting the String Boot app. I got this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookAlarmNotificationService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookAlarmNotificationRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookAlarmNotificationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.nicinc.persistence.domain.backend.BookAlarmNotification
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookAlarmNotificationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.nicinc.persistence.domain.backend.BookAlarmNotification
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.nicinc.persistence.domain.backend.BookAlarmNotification
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: why not post the REAL exception? the one at the end of the stack trace, and include the stack trace on it

Comment: Looks like you have swapped the annotations for `AlarmNotification` and `BookAlarmNotification`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="d_intervenant_tc")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="Type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Intervenant {

}

@Entity
public class Affilie extends Intervenant{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) document we find in Section 11.1.38 (PDF page 471):

> The `MappedSuperclass` annotation designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate table defined for it.
>
> ...
>
> A class designated with the `MappedSuperclass` annotation can be mapped in the same way as an entity except that the mappings will apply only to its subclasses since no table exists for the mapped
>   superclass itself.

So the problem originates from the fact, that your Entity class `AlarmNotification` is incorrectly used as a base class for `BookAlarmNotification`. As noted in the comment of "Abdullah Khan", the correct way of annotating would be:

Annotate the abstract base class `AlarmNotification` like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name= "ALARM_TYPE") 
public abstract class AlarmNotification  implements Serializable {
   //..
}
```

Use the `@Entity` annotation for the class that inherit from it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_book_alarm_notification")
public class BookAlarmNotification extends AlarmNotification {
   //..
}
```

Thus, the *UnsatisfiedDependencyException / IllegalArgumentException*

> Not a managed type: class com.nicinc.persistence.domain.backend.BookAlarmNotification

shouldn't occur any longer as it now exists as managed Entity in your application.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have another type extending AlarmNotification (ComputerAlarmNotification). With this approach I couldn't use InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE, because I should use another table: t_computer_alarm_notification, and I want to user only 1 table

Comment: If I read this [page](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/) correctly I have the feeling you should not be using **@MappedSuperClass** & **@Inheritance** together since they are dirrefent strategies.